# ! LaTeX Error: File `siunitx.sty' not found

Tags: installing

While compiling a document I get

```
! LaTeX Error: File `siunitx.sty' not found.
```

But there is this file on the system:

```
locate siunitx.sty
/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lwarp/lwarp-siunitx.sty
/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/siunitx/siunitx.sty
```

The output of

```
which pdflatex
```

is

```
/usr/bin/pdflatex
```

What is the problem?

Comment: presumably the latex you are using is not the texlive 2017 one, what does `which pdflatex` (or equivalent command) give as the path to the latex program? (or alternatively if you look at the log of a `article` class document what is the path to `article.cls`)

Comment: I just see you asked about installing tex via `sudo apt-get` that would not install under /usr/local/texlive, that would install a system texlive, the one in /usr/local is an installation of a vanilla texlive from tug